# how to control door using SIM900a

Tags: arduino, gsm

I need help I'm doing project about opening and closing the door using SIM900a.. it says that no errors but it doesn't work !! I used AT commands and it supposes to send notification to the user using sms when theres knocking, motion at home, high temperature and when theirs smoke please help please please

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
#include "pins_arduino.h" 
#include <String.h> 
SoftwareSerial SIM900(7, 8); //tx & rx pins
String msg = String("");
char inchar;


int x = 0;
int y = 0;
float z =0;
int PIR_sensor = 12;
int door_lock = 4 ; //close the door
int door_lock1 = 5 ;
int led = 11;
int led1 = 10; //red led
int mic= 6;
int Gas_sensor = A0;
float Tem_sensor = A1;
float temp =0.0;
String textForGAS ;
String textForPIR ;
String textForTAM ;
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(19200);
pinMode(PIR_sensor, INPUT);
pinMode(door_lock, OUTPUT);
pinMode(door_lock1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(door_lock, LOW);
digitalWrite(door_lock1, LOW);
digitalWrite(led, LOW);
digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
// wake up the GSM shield
SIM900.begin(19200);
delay(20000); // give time to log on to network.
SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1r"); // set SMS mode to text
delay(100);
SIM900.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0r");
// blurt out contents of new SMS upon receipt to the GSM shield’s serial out
delay(100);
Serial.println("Ready…");
}

void sendSMS(String message)
{
SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
delay(100);
SIM900.println("AT + CMGS = \"+96896089681\"");
delay(100);
SIM900.println(message);
delay(100);
SIM900.println((char)26);
delay(100);
SIM900.println();
delay(5000);
}
void loop()
{
//If a character comes in from the cellular module…
if (SIM900.available())
{
inchar = SIM900.read();
Serial.println(inchar);
if (inchar == '#')
{
delay(10);

inchar = SIM900.read();
if (inchar == 'a')
{
delay(10);
inchar = SIM900.read();
if (inchar == '0')
{
digitalWrite(door_lock, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led, LOW);
}
else if (inchar == '1')
{
digitalWrite(door_lock1, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
}
delay(10);
inchar = SIM900.read();
if (inchar == 'b')
{
inchar = SIM900.read();
if (inchar == '0')
{
digitalWrite(PIR_sensor, LOW);
}
else if (inchar == '1')
{
digitalWrite(PIR_sensor, HIGH);
}
}
SIM900.println("AT+CMGD=1,4"); // delete all SMS
}
}
}
Gas_sensor = (analogRead(A0));
PIR_sensor = (digitalRead(12));
Tem_sensor = (analogRead(A1));
temp = Tem_sensor * 0.48828125;
//program for GAS sensor
if (temp > 70.0)
{
textForTAM = "Alarm ! The degree of Tamperture is :n ";
textForTAM.concat(temp);
textForTAM = textForTAM +"C";
Serial.println(textForTAM);

sendSMS(textForGAS);
delay(1000);
do {
z = (analogRead(A0));
 } 
while (z >= 141.312);
 }
 //program for GAS sensor
 if (Gas_sensor > 500)
 {
 textForGAS = "Alarm ! there is Gas by rate :n ";
 textForGAS.concat(Gas_sensor);
 Serial.println(textForGAS);
 sendSMS(textForGAS);
 delay(1000);
 }
 //program for PIR sensor
 if (digitalRead(12) == HIGH)
{
textForPIR = "Warnning ! n theres's a motion ";
textForPIR.concat(PIR_sensor);
Serial.println(textForPIR);
sendSMS(textForPIR);
delay(1000);
}
}
```

thank you

Comment: Please, format and comment your code.

Comment: Write a smaller program that just sends an SMS and see if that works.  That will let you figure out if it's the sending of the SMS that goes wrong or the detection of the event you want to report.

Comment: `SoftwareSerial SIM900(7, 8); //tx & rx pins`  Note that the SoftwareSerial constructor lists the RX pin first and then the TX pin, which is the opposite of your comment, so double-check that.

Comment: when im trying the code and the circuit yes i use small one like only leds but still it doesn't ... i did what you said i changed them but still no action..... thank you